# My function won't run?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm getting tired of firebug telling my vars aren't defined...

I have a button: next. When the button is clicked, I want it to load a php page into a div, assigning the php page the variable representing the next page.

To do this, I have a variable crntpage that stores the value of the current page. In order to calculate what the var for the next page must be I have a function called next which calculates the value and returns it.

Let's assume that we are on page 5:

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$.ajax({
    url: 'pagination.php',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    success: function (pages) {
                last = pages['last'];
                crntpage = 1;

                function nxt(b) {
                    if (b == last) {
                        next  = last;
                    } else {
                        next = b + 1;
                    }
                    return next;
                }

                $('#next').live('click', function() {
                    crntpage(next);
                    $('#content').load('getposts.php?pagenum=' + nxt(crntpage));
                    return false;
                });
    }
});
});
```

html

```
<div id="previous"> 
        <a href=''> <-Previous</a>
</div>
```

I keep getting an error saying that next isn't defined. My guess is because my nxt function is not receiving the value of last. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can use firebug's debugger and set a break point and step through the code.

Comment: btw, I don't see you defining `next` outside the context of the `nxt()` function. How does the `crntpage(next)` work?

Comment: and you should take the `live` out of the `success callback`. it will cause you problems that way ... like many reponses to one single `click`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do with the `nxt` function can be accomplished more idiomatically with `Math.min()`:

```
$('#next').live('click', function() {
    crntpage = Math.min(crntpage + 1, last);
    $('#content').load('getposts.php?pagenum=' + crntpage);
    return false;
});
```

You should also prefix variable declarations with the `var` keyword, so as not to pollute the global namespace.

Here's the revised code together:

```
$(function() {

    var currentPage = 1;
    var last = 1;

    $('#next').live('click', function() {
        currentPage = Math.min(currentPage + 1, last);
        $('#content').load('getposts.php?pagenum=' + currentPage);
        return false;
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: 'pagination.php',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",    
        cache: false,
        success: function (pages) {
            last = pages['last'];
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: but he wants that `if (b == last) next  = last;` and modulus doesn't give'm that !!

Comment: I know you're just basing it on the OP's question, but to the OP: `.live()` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7. If you're on 1.7+, you should be using `.on()`. If you must, you can still delegate to document as the listener, but I bet you could find a closer ancestor to `#next`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you didn't define `next`. (or maybe it is defined in the part of your code that you didn't post here, I don't know) Have you tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var next = ''; //defining the variable first, then you set it below in nxt()
$.ajax({
    url: 'pagination.php',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    success: function (pages) { 
                last = pages['last'];
                crntpage = 1;

                function nxt(b) {
                    if (b == last) {
                        next  = last;
                    } else {
                        next = b + 1;
                    }
                    return next;
                }

                $('#next').live('click', function() {
                    crntpage(next);
                    $('#content').load('getposts.php?pagenum=' + nxt(crntpage));
                    return false;
                });
    }
});
});
```